# Feed me with Google sheets and matrix fields

Tags: plugin-feedme, craft4

Our client delivered a list of products in the form of a Google Sheet.
Some products contain some extra information which should we presented in the form of a list on the website.
Currently these items are just extra rows under the product.
I understand that these items will need to be converted to a single cell in order for the product to be contained in only 1 row.
But I'm confused on how I this can then be imported with Feed Me into a matrix field.

Does anyone have any best practices?